# FCM Web convert Android webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Create an FCM reception using JavaScript
Upload to IIS 10 and link with HTTPS
Completed PC and mobile testing.
Its address is https://car369.net/msg_test.ejs

We have both Android and Windows environments
Try to convert to web view and display.
However, I get a browser error that doesn't support the test results.

We try to solve the webview client
Through Advancedwebview, geckowebview
I tested it and got the same result.

how can i this?

**Android ErrodMessage**

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser 
doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", 
source: https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-app.js (1)
```

**FCM main.ejs**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.18.0/firebase-messaging.js'></script>
<script>
//FCM User Code
const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "fir-yr.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-yr.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-yr",
    storageBucket: "fir-yr.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxx"
};

//firebase setting
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const onMsg = firebase.messaging();

//Get Token
function clickToken(){
    onMsg.requestPermission()
        .then(function(){
            return onMsg.getToken();
        })
        .then(function(token){
            console.log(token);
            $('#token').val(token)
        })
        .catch(function(arr){
            alert(arr)
            console.log("Error Occured");
            console.log('err',arr);
        });
}
<script>
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.18.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.18.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "fir-yr.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-yr.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-yr",
    storageBucket: "fir-yr.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

//firebase setting
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
    console.log('Background payload :',payload);
    //title contents
    const title = payload.data.title;
    //body contents
    const options = {
        body: payload.data.message,
        icon: payload.data.icon,
        click_action : payload.data.click_action,
        data: {click_action:payload.data.click_action}
    };
    //show message
    return self.registration.showNotification(title,options);
});


//Noti Click Event
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    console.log('event',event);
    console.log('clients :', clients);

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    }).then(function() {
        return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.click_action);
    });
 
    console.log('promise',promise);
    event.waitUntil(promise);

});
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private WebView myWebView;
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
            }
        });

        String url = "https://car369.net/msg_test.ejs";
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.webview">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="android:webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
        android:value="true"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you for answer!!